# Spacy list comprehension for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, spacy

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
Index    Text

0        When can I go to Canada?
1        Who is king Arthur?
2        Can you give me the email of Norton?
```

Using spacy I am trying to extract the names from each row of the dataframe such that my output looks like this

```
Index    Text                                     Name

0        When can I go to Canada?                 
1        Who is king Arthur?                      Arthur
2        Can you give me the email of Norton?     Norton
```

I have been somewhat successful using the following code

```
df['Name'] = [nlp(x).ents for x in df['Text']]
```

But it outputs all sorts of entities and not just names for example I'll also get 'Canada' as an output, which I don't want. So, I modified code to this

```
df['Name'] = [token.label_ for token in nlp(x).ents for x in df['Text']]
```

But suddenly I get the error

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why is the list comprehension not working?
Following the code example from here https://spacy.io/

Comment: Please add all relevant code to repro the issue.

Comment: `!pip install spacy

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

These are the only lines of code missing from the example besides the normal dataframe code.

Comment: Do you expect only a single name per input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mostly yes. The only reason I am interested in names is because I want to find all rows that contain a name. A 0 or 1. It doesn't matter if it's one or two but in 99.9% of cases the input will have a single name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```py
import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def get_persons( text ):
    good_ents = {"PERSON" , "ORG"}
    doc = nlp(text)
    persons = [i.text for i in doc.ents if i.label_ in good_ents]
    return persons 

df["name"] = df.apply( lambda x : get_persons( x["Text"] ) , axis = 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks @LukasP it works but I have a questions why do you also search for "ORG" label when I only need to search for "PERSON"?

Comment: The small model `_sm` for English is not perfect for Person recognition. When I ran it on my machine, it failed to catch `Norton`, because it was labelled as an `ORG`. That is consistent with Spacy's demo ( https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent ). Therefore, to get the outcome you want, `ORG` was needed. 

Maybe if you tried bigger language models `_md` or `_lg` it would yield better results without `ORG`.

Comment: I can run the large models, not a problem. I am just learning this so used a small model.